# DataGridView - force empty DataSource for anonymous objects

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I have a `DataGridView` which has two columns designed: their `DataPropertyName` are `Name` and `Value`.

`DataSource` for this `DGV` comes from collection of `SomeObject` class which looks like:

```
public class SomeObject
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Value { get; set; }
    public int SomeOtherProp1 { get; set; }
    public int SomeOtherProp2 { get; set; }
}
```

I want only `Name` and `Value` properties be used in `DataSource`, so I create an anonymous object with those two properties (`someObjectCollection` is a collection of `SomeObject objects`):

```
dgv.DataSource = someObjectCollection.Select(o => new { o.Name, o.Value }).ToArray();
```

And that is ok - what I need to achieve now, is to manually assign an empty collection to `dgv.DataSource` to clear it out.

I cannot assign `null`, because then the DataGridView control just disappears on the form.
I also would ommit creating an additional viev model class with only those two properties used in DataSource.

So, is there any other way?

Comment: i was going to suggest using another model as the data source and then populating that with your select. Then i noticed your last sentence. Id possibly suggest trying to fix your disheartening `dgv` then null the `data source` or set it to a blank `object` then clearing the rows?

Comment: The grid should not disappear. Do you have a minimal example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the set the empty result with the last valid result, case the object is null .

Comment: Ok, I did it this way:  `dgv.DataSource = Enumerable.Empty<SomeObject>().Select(o => new { o.Name, o.Value }).ToArray();`